# how to fetch posts from Api in chunks or parts?

Tags: posts, api

I'm working on a Hubspot Api and trying to fetch all blog posts through api, but the api limit is only 20 post each time and i need to get 1960 blog posts. So how i supposed to do that?

Is there any way to do this with ajax or java script or through a loop that increase limit every time

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    include 'wp-load.php';
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/taxonomy.php');

    $apiKey = "9****966-***************";
    $getArgs = array('timeout' => 120);

    // Grab all blog posts . '&archived=false&offset=0&limit=300' total=1906
    $response = wp_remote_get('https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=' . $apiKey . '&archived=false&limit=1960&offset=0', $getArgs);
    $output = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

    $results = $output['objects'];
    foreach ($results as $item) {
        $postStatus = 'publish';

        if ($item['blog_author']['email'] !== '') {

            $user = get_user_by('email', $item['blog_author']['email']);

            if ($user == false) {

                $user = wp_insert_user(array(
                    'user_login' => $item['blog_author']['email'],
                    'user_email' => $item['blog_author']['email'],
                    'first_name' => $item['blog_author']['full_name'],
                    'user_pass' => substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'),
                        0, 10),
                ));
                $user = get_user_by('id', $user);
            }
        } else {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
        }

        if ($item['state'] == 'DRAFT') {
            $postStatus = 'draft';
        } elseif ($item['state'] == 'SCHEDULED') {
            $postStatus = 'future';
        }
        $categories = $item['topic_ids'];
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key' => 'hubspot_id',
            'meta_value' => $item['id'],
            'meta_compare' => '='
        );

        $exists = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($exists->post_count == 0) {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_title' => $item['name'],
                'post_content' => $item['post_body'],
                'post_status' => $postStatus,
                //'post_category' => $categories,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['publish_date'] / 1000),
                'post_author' => $user->ID
            ));
        } else {
            while ($exists->have_posts()) {
                $exists->the_post();
                $post_id = wp_update_post(array(
                    'ID' => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_title' => $item['name'],
                    'post_content' => $item['post_body'],
                    'post_status' => $postStatus,
                    //'post_category' => $categories,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['publish_date'] / 1000),
                    'post_author' => $user->ID
                ));
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        if (!empty($post_id) && !is_null($post_id)) {
            $image_url = $item['featured_image'];
            if ($image_url !== '' && isset($image_url)) {
                $imageAltText = $item['featured_image_alt_text'];

                $temp_file = download_url($image_url);
                $file = array(
                    'name' => basename($image_url), // ex: wp-header-logo.png
                    'type' => wp_check_filetype($temp_file, null)['type'],
                    'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
                    'error' => 0,
                    'size' => filesize($temp_file),
                );

                $overrides = [
                    'test_form' => false,
                    'test_size' => true,
                ];

                $results = wp_handle_sideload($file, $overrides);
                if (empty($results['error'])) {
                    $filename = $results['file']; // Full path to the file
                    $local_url = $results['url'];  // URL to the file in the uploads dir
                    $type = $results['type']; // MIME type of the file

                    // Set attachment data
                    $attachment = [
                        'post_mime_type' => $type,
                        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($imageAltText),
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'inherit'
                    ];

                    // Create the attachment
                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $post_id);
                    if (has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
                        $oldthumbnail = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
                        wp_delete_attachment($oldthumbnail, true);
                    }

                    // Define attachment metadata
                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename);

                    // Assign metadata to attachment
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

                    // And finally assign featured image to post
                    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
                }
            }
            if (!add_post_meta($post_id, 'hubspot_id', $item['id'], true)) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'hubspot_id', $item['id']);
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        $topicIds = $item['topic_ids'];
        $getArgs = array('timeout' => 120);
        $topics = [];
        foreach ($topicIds as $topicId) {

            $response = wp_remote_get('https://api.hubapi.com/blogs/v3/topics/' . $topicId . '?hapikey=9****966-***************', $getArgs);
            $topics[] = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

            foreach ($topics as $topic) {
                $catarr = array(
                    'cat_name' => $topic['name'],
                    'category_description' => $topic['description'],
                    'category_nicename' => $topic['slug'],
                    'taxonomy' => 'category'
                );
                $category_id = wp_insert_category($catarr);
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $category_id, "category", true);
                $default_category = (int)get_option('default_category');
                if (in_category($default_category, $post_id)) {
                    // get list of all the post categories
                    $post_categories = get_the_category($post_id);

                    // count the total of the categories
                    $total_categories = count($post_categories);

                    // check if the post is in more than 1 category (the default one and more..)
                    if ($total_categories > 1) {
                        // remove the default category from the post
                        wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, $default_category, 'category');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Assume you mean the Hubspot API limit is 20? Have you thought about using the `posts_per_page` option and the `offset` parameter? [Pagination Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) and [WPSE Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192557/changing-posts-per-page-and-offset-with-pre-get-posts)

Comment: I am inserting posts from api outside of wordpress environment and able to add only 20 post each time as per Api limit, total post count in 1906 and if i add limit to infinit i.e. 99999 the api call will stops at 125 posts and the categories of the post at this limit not working means all post goes to `uncategorized` so i need to call only 20 post each time but how i suppose to part all posts in chunks so after every time only 20 posts will insert and then the offset will change automatically thats i cant figure out how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to wrap what you've done up there into a function and do something like.

```
for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= 1906; $counter += 20) {

    $responseURL = 'https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=' . $apiKey . '&archived=false&limit=20&offset=' . $counter;

    $response = wp_remote_get($responseURL, $getArgs);
    process_API_results($response);

    $restcounter++;

    if($restcounter == 6) { // works out to 120 posts then stops for 2 mins to prevent Hubspot stopping sync
        sleep(120);
        $restcounter = 0;
    }
}
```

If you `echo` out those URL requests you get

https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=&archived=false&limit=20&offset=0
https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=&archived=false&limit=20&offset=20
https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=&archived=false&limit=20&offset=40
https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=&archived=false&limit=20&offset=60
https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=&archived=false&limit=20&offset=80

...
etc

Comment: Thanks for answering @Bysander I tried this but it stops at `125` posts i need to add interval or any thing that stop the execution after `20` posts and starts it automatically after some interval

Comment: See the update - you can use `sleep()` function to make the script wait - I've put 2 mins (120 seconds) but this may be overkill