# is_home and is_frontpage always true

Tags: theme-development, front-end, frontpage

I'm trying to limit the number of posts on the homepage but is_home() and is_frontpage() always seem to return true (even when I'm browsing /page/2/, /page/3/ and so on).

I've basically duplicated the twenty fifteen theme and trying to make my own based on that one. I deleted every function in functions.php (also removed any calls to those functions) and currently I only have this function in there:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_frontpage_posts' );

function limit_frontpage_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }

  return $query;
}
```

Basically I want one post on the frontpage and on every other page whatever limit has been set in the admin panel. The code above is showing only one post on *every* page. Any idea's what's going wrong?

Comment: Under `Settings -> Reading` have you set a homepage or is the homepage also your blog ( which is default functionality )? It would also be best to test against the current query by prefixing your conditional statements with `$query->is_front_page()` and `$query->is_main_query()` so it doesn't run the filter on *all* queries on the front page.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong, the second page of your home page is still your home page. If you want to check if it's only the first page, check if [`! is_paged()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged).

That said, you can't just change posts per page and have it work properly, because when you're on the 2nd page and beyond, the post it starts on is calculated based on the current number of posts per page- WordPress doesn't know that your first page only had one post and the 2nd should start at post #2, it will just multiply posts per page by the page number, so posts will be skipped.

[See this answer for an explanation and solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155758/have-different-number-of-posts-on-first-page).

Comment: I was just about to post the same link to my answer :-)

Comment: I didn't realise each page was still considered the home page. Is it possible to make an entirely different page the home page, with a query that only selects the latest post? Or is the link you posted the way to go for this kind of thing?

Comment: I would implement the pagination fix on the linked answer. You can create a new question here with your attempted code if you are having trouble making it work.