# Pagination Not working on Home Page with 2 Query

Tags: wp-query, customization, loop, pagination, homepage

I have two loops in home page (index.php)

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
    );

    $another_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $another_query->have_posts() ) {
      $i = 0;
      while ($another_query->have_posts()) : $another_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if($i == 0) { ?>
          <div class="col s8">
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-magazine-grid-big', get_post_format() ); ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($i == 1 || $i == 2) { ?>
          <div class="col s4">
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-magazine-grid-small', get_post_format() ); ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>

       <?php $i++;
        if($i != 0) { ?>

          <?php
        } ?>

        <?php
      endwhile;

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

And another one

```
 <?php

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'paged'     => $paged,
      'posts_per_page' => 2,
      'offset' => 3,
      'orderby'        => 'date',
      'order'          => 'DESC',
    );
    $args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $i=0;
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $query;
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

          <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-rest', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php  $i++; endwhile;    ?>
      <?php previous_posts_link();next_posts_link();
     ?>
    <?php
    // Need this to reset the query
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    ?>
```

I want pagination on last loop..
But it's not working...

Comment: 'offset' does not work together with pagination. find a different way to exclude the three first posts; the Codex has examples; https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

Comment: @Michael although you are correct, the page you linked to is a pile of crap. Unfortunately that is just one of those many really poorly written pages in the codex

Comment: @PieterGoosen - to offset three posts via 'pre_get_posts' will work in this case, as the second query uses the default values for 'orderby' and 'order'. in any other case, for example returning random post in the second query, would imho better work with excluding exact the previously shown posts. 
-  the shown code has other flaws as not using the proper pagination codes, and not taking into account that on paginated pages, the first three posts should possibly also be paginated. unfortunately, the question does not contain any explanation what is really intended with the code.

Comment: @Michael if the first three posts needs to be paginated, then this would be a duplicate of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155758/31545) ;-) As for random ordering, your method you linked to will not work, paging randomly ordered queries is a mess. IMHO, it still stays bad practice to just simply skip posts in the loop. Much better to remove posts through the `post__not_in` parameter through `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I totally agree to your remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to run a custom query for your second loop. You can simply adjust the main query to your needs. It is always never a good idea to run custom queries in place of the main query. One big issue is always pagination, WordPress disregards all other queries, and only focus on the main query when it comes to page functionality. I have done a quite extensive post on this, so be sure to check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

We can drop the second query, and just use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. Because we use offset here, we need to manually calculate pagination as we are breaking `WP_Query`'s process which calculates pagination

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
    ) {
        // Get the current page number
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
        // Set offset
        $offset = 3;
        // Set posts per page
        $ppp = 2;

        if ( !$q->is_paged() ) {
            // Set page one offset
            $q->set( 'offset',         $offset );
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp    );
        } else {
            // Handle pagination for paged pages
            $offset = $offset + ( ( $current_page - 1 ) * $ppp );
            $q->set( 'offset',         $offset );
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp    );
        }
    }
});
```

You should now have your main query correctly paginated with one problem, the last page might, depending on the amount of posts, 404'ing. To adjust for that, we need to adjust the `$found_posts` property of the main query.

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, $q ) 
{
    $offset = 3;

    if(    $q->is_home() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
    ) {
        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;
    }

    return $found_posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Needless to say, your main loop on your homepage should now just be as follow

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts()) : 
        the_post(); 

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-rest', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;
    previous_posts_link();
    next_posts_link();
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but I think it should be like this:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'post',
  'paged'           => $paged,
  'posts_per_page'  => 2,
  'offset'          => 3,
  'orderby'         => 'date',
  'order'           => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. `offset` breaks pagination, so you would need to manually recalculate pagination and offset for each and every page. It is quite a messy process ;-)